# How to get a list of timezones in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to know, how to get a list of timezones in Ruby 2.0?

Comment: Do you need it for ruby on rails?

Comment: Try: include ActiveSupport
TimeZone.all

Answer (score 31, accepted):

with rails a simple way is:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
```

Comment: This only works if you've got Rails installed, and is pretty heavyweight for just getting a list of timezones.

Comment: And use `puts TimeZone.all.map(&:name).sort` to an alphabetical list of the names.

Comment: Another Rails option is `ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.keys` which is pretty quick. The output is the same as @JoshuaPinter

Comment: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all

Comment: Of course, use ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.keys.sort to get a sorted version - just as an addition to @Asdrubal comment

Answer (score 26):

If you want a ruby only solution, (rails independent) you can use the [tzinfo](http://rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/frames) gem.

```
require 'tzinfo'

TZInfo::Timezone.all_country_zone_identifiers
TZInfo::Timezone.all_country_zones
#...
#America/Chicago
#America/Indiana/Tell_City
#America/Indiana/Knox
#America/Menominee
#America/North_Dakota/Center
#America/North_Dakota/New_Salem
#America/North_Dakota/Beulah
#America/Denver
#America/Boise
#...
```

Comment: Note that `tzinfo` comes by default with Rails 6.0+

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer for two reasons:



1. The question didn't specify Rails, and using just tzinfo is a better option if you don't want to load all rails dependencies


2. The tzinfo lists all identifiers found on IANA database, while the ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all actually only list some selected timezones (the tzinfo version will list today 311 identifiers, while the version with ActiveSupport will only list 151)